# Treeview node spacing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, treeview

I am working with a treeview and I want to reduce the whitespace between the nodes. see picture below as an example of how the nodes are represented.

[image]

This is a full scale replication of how the nodes show, with no formatting, no div placed around the node it still comes out with the same spacing.

I have tried setting the `NodeSpacing` on all Leaf, Parent, Root and Node styles and none of which has helped.

As I am using a treeview control from Visual Studio which at the moment looks like this

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server" ExpandDepth="1">

</asp:TreeView>
```

where I would expect the nodes to be closer they are rendering like this.

I would be grateful for any and all assistance on how I can reduce the spacing.

Thanks

edit 1

[image]

Comment: You should inspect your rendered HTML, thus you can modify the CSS styles involved.

Comment: @JorgeCalvoMorales the rendered html is a mess and is as per the image in my edit to the question.

Comment: Look at "viewOrFunction Node" class, you can add an style in any of your css files (usually styles.css) to modify that class. Look, it's better if you "play" a little bit with your DOM inspector (with Google Chrome for example), then you can modify your style on the air just to be sure you are doing the right thing.

Comment: @JorgeCalvoMorales I would love to use chrome for my inspector however I am forced to work with IE8, and we are only just going up to IE11 in a slow fashion,.  viewOrFunction and Node are my own custom classes anyway which are giving styles to the nodes, but to reduce the gap on this anything I do and try and 'play with' seems to increase the gap